# Weird variable value on jQuery and Ajax loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code

```
var varheight;
$('.item-content').load("content/content.html", function(){
    varheight = $('.item-content').css('height');
    $('.item-content').css({height: 0});
    $('.item-content').animate({'height': varheight}, 1000);
});
```

What I want it to do is load the contents in the container, so I can get the total container size after the loading, then, set the height to 0 before the users see it, and then, slowly, by animation, increase the height to it's size.

Seems pretty straight forward and the code should be working... but, something weird is happening... if I check the value of `varheight` with an alert like this:

```
var varheight;
$('.item-content').load("content/content.html", function(){
    varheight = $('.item-content').css('height');
    alert(varheight);
    $('.item-content').css({height: 0});
    $('.item-content').animate({'height': varheight}, 1000);
});
```

I get 0. It should not be, because I've just loaded a lot of content inside the .item-content

The weird part is that if I remove the next 2 lines, like that:

```
var varheight;
$('.item-content').load("content/content.html", function(){
    varheight = $('.item-content').css('height');
    alert(varheight);
});
```

I get the true value (about 1300px, that's not really the important point here).

I can't help but wonder, how come can that value change even if these lines have not been reached yet? How can they have effect on value of this variable if it is never changed again and, worst of all, the alert comes BEFORE these lines??

I'm losing my mind here!

Comment: tried it... no luck. exactly same behavior :/

Comment: well, it seems Vega deleted its comments, but he was right! there was some issue with another part of the code causing the height to be hard-coded to 0! fixed it and now everything runs fine!

Comment: Post your solution as the answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there was another parallel script running which was hard-coding the height to 0 before this one, causing the problem!

Script removed, problem solved.